# How to load multiple records using lightning data service

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to load multiple records using lightning data service without using any apex controllers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Salesforce Docs:

> Lightning Data Service supports primitive DML operations—create, read,
>   update, and delete. It operates on one record at a time, which you
>   retrieve or modify using the record ID.

SO you need to create multiple instance of it to handle bulk operation which is not recommended.

[Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm)

Answer (score 3):

LDS is not intended for bulk data loads, and has no real query capabilities beyond the current object. It is meant for lightweight quick actions and the such.o load or save a lot of records at once will cause a significant performance penalty.